# How does one oppose a dictatorship, with no resources?

Tags: armed-conflict, dictatorship

Imagine the following situation: you live in a large country that has been ruled for a whole generation by a dictator. There is only a semblance of civil institutions, but in fact all courts follow orders from above and bend laws as they wish; all elections are systematically faked, and the parliament is full of dummies that vote unanimously for anything that would please the dictator. There has been opposition, but nearly all its members either got in prison, died under various circumstances, or fled the country to avoid the two former outcomes. The same has happened with independent media, and the official media is full of militaristic and nationalistic propaganda, believed by the majority of population, especially the older generations.

Street protests happen from time to time, after arrests of popular oppositioners or new repressive laws, but they are violently suppressed. As a result, less and less people are willing to protest openly. The youth are afraid of arrests, fines, and physical violence by police, and few go out. Typically, the arrests for taking part in any demonstration are about 15 days, and fines are typically 15% to 30% of average monthly salary, but there is a chance of multy-year prison sentences for public expressions of opinion, such as demonstrations or even posts in social media. And although these chances are low, they scare the youths a lot. And the older people just believe that the safest thing is to do sit quietly in any circumstances (this is how they have survived the previous regime), and many of them agree with the state propaganda that wars and repressions are necessary for some greater good.

Now the country has started a war against its smaller neighbor for no obvious reason. Perhaps, the dictator just could not tolerate having a successful democracy in a neighboring country. So now thousands of people are dying. You feel personally responsible for all this shit and want to stop it.

The problem is, you are nobody. You are a young researcher in computer linguistics with no resistance-related skills and all wealth destroyed by a recent market crash. You have a network of several hundred people with similar pacifist and democratic views, but most of them are young hipsters that are very afraid of any violence; a large proportion of them has recently left the country. So basically, you are alone and with no resources. You try to agitate your community for new demonstrations, but the passive part of it does nothing because of fear, and the active part mostly prefers to emigrate. And you have no idea of an efficient action that could help end the dictatorship or the war.

The country's economy suffers a lot because of its international isolation following the war, so you hope that there some elites displeased with it and they might arrange a coup. But you don't know who these elites are and whether they exist at all, because everything about money and power in your country happens in the shadow. Of course, the dictator has some friends that  owe him money and power. But the dictator's power seems to be their only shield against public anger, so these friends seem to be loyal to the dictator. And it is not obvious whether there are any other types of elites in the country.

The dictator himself is not likely going to end the war, because his reign is based on the fear he imposes both to his own citizens (of repressions), and to other countries (of larger wars). And if he stops the war, he would lose his reputation of a strong and dangerous leader, less people would be afraid of him, and he would be overthrown faster. So he is going to continue the war as long as possible, and repress the citizens who oppose the war as traitors. Therefore, for ending the war, it seems necessary to end the dictatorship.

So the questions are:

1. What is a realistic way the war could end, except the natural death of the dictator (that might happen in tens of years)?
2. What can a person described above do, to increase the likelihood of ending the dictatorship and the war as soon as possible?

Both opinions and reading sources are welcome.

Comment: With regard to: "You feel personally responsible" -> please work on changing this view. You are NOT responsible for what's happening. There's a middle way between being apathetic, and believing yourself to be the superhero that can fix a situation. I find power through figuring out what my own personal "lines in the sand" are. I don't work for unethical companies. I donate blood every 8 weeks. If presented with an extraordinary opportunity, I vow to take it (I have been able to save a life one time). This won't end a war, but it's what a normal person can do. And it's about character.

Comment: And I know what I'm posting doesn't feel like enough. It never will. Any sane person living through a war wishes they could wave a wand and make it end. Or apartheid. Or climate change. Or any number of other horrific acts that a leader can visit upon a population. Part of the reason that movies get made about a normal person going above and beyond to save a single life is because even that is extraordinarily difficult to do. 

Anyway - I hope others have some actionable ideas that help you. My take is just one dimension. You're not alone in how you feel.

Comment: You don't follow advice from internet users who are not in-country and are at no risk themselves.  Like the genius with the Sabotage Manual link.  If you want to act, do it well on the side of non-violence and preferably within acceptable parameters of what's not yet been rendered illegal in your country.  You are not responsible for this shit.  But never vote for this loser, ever.  But I am afraid this is not an answerable question here, in the sense that it is strictly a matter of opinion what to answer.

Comment: > You don't follow advice from internet users who are not in-country and are at no risk themselves.

— That is exactly why I ask this question to users from other countries speaking another language. Those who are inside are inclined to be too frightened to just think calmly and logically about the situation.

Comment: People in my country just did everything wrong. Eventually, the regime crumbled on its own. Since I have no reputation, I won't be able to write a full answer.

Comment: Great "question" sir - I didn't know SE was a platform to make political statements.

Comment: @Magicsowon If you have enough reputation to write a coment, it should be no problem to write an answer.

Comment: @csstudent1418 SE is a GAME ! Nothing more, nothing less. It thrives entirely on peoples addictive desire to express and enforce their political opinion. In that sense, political statements is what SE is all about. Not just the politics stack, but all of them. Just so you know.

Comment: @DavidDale You're putting your hopes up too high I'm afraid. Do you see that stuff in the upper right corner of your screen? That is what Stack Exchange is all about. Your question got closed because that's the opinion of the players with the highest score. This is not a serious politics platform. It's a game. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A long time ago, some Frenchman was facing a similar problem, watching train loads of weapons roll to the front lines. In order to have any effect at all, he took one of his shoes. Not much more than a wooden clog, he jammed it in between the strands of one rail of a railway intersection, thereby causing the oncoming train to veer off on one rail, while going straight ahead on the other. As a result, the train derailed, destroying it and all its content. After the fact, the Frenchman took his shoe and disappeared without a trace, or so it seemed.

The Frenchman's wooden shoe was called a 'sabot' and the act he performed, has since been referred to as 'sabotage'.

Don't blame me for this answer. You asked for it.

Know what you want to do, why you want it and how far you are willing to go to achieve this goal. Unless you actively obstruct it, you may very well end up performing the same atrocities you are trying to prevent. Set your own moral standards and judge all of your own future actions by those standards. Write them down, so you don't forget. Your absolutely indisputable number one task will be to stay sane. Use your own feed back to stay on track. Write things down and read what you've written. It helps.

You're on your own. Make sure it stays that way. Do not seek alliance unless it absolutely can't be avoided. The blame is a very precious thing. Make sure it's yours and yours alone. 'Friends' are a hazard.

Do not expect any reward, honor or public recognition. There will be none. More often than not, those who do what you are considering, end up getting severely mentally deranged in the process. The world will not like you when you are done. Just check the down votes to this answer to see why. Downvoters don't read.

Say goodbye to everything you love, own, appreciate or are in any way attached to. You will loose it. Operate as far away as possible from your own doorstep.

Be inventive. The entire world is your resource.

Stick to the facts. To your own personal experience as to that of any other living human being, dying is something other people do. For all you know, this entire universe stops existing the moment you die. Contemplate your actions in the light of these facts. You can't sacrifice your life for someone or something else. It is simply not possible. This is you being you for your reasons. Nothing else.

Comment: Can you provide a source for that shoe in the traintrack story? [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sabotage#Etymology) mentions a similar story saying it's a false etymology.

Comment: @JJJ The story isn't necessarily true.  Any source confirming it, doesn't change that. Wikipedia is hardly the gospel truth and even the gospel truth itself is frequently questioned. In this case the story serves the purpose of illustrating the importance of taking the first step. Every step ever taken by anyone is in some way or another a first step. It's taking it that matters.

Comment: I really love this answer. Because you touch on the moral risks associated with this route. My comment to the OP counseled normal, everyday, principled actions precisely because I *only* see inadvertantly terrible things coming from trying to be the main character in a movie ("You may very well end up performing the same atrocities you are trying to prevent"). But certainly I don't get to decide what others do.

Comment: @HFBrowning Good deeds matter. Also small ones. Even now that  I know, it's still hard to stay focused and remind myself again and again that discipline of thought is the only way through adversities. Suppressing every notion that killing an enemy could possibly lead to victory. The most effective way to reduce the number of bad guys is by not becoming one, but it ain't easy.

Answer (score 8):

> What is a realistic way the war could end, except the natural death of
> the dictator (that might happen in tens of years)?

There isn't one (other than the dictator losing the war at the hands of outsiders with which the dictator is at war).

> What can a person described above do, to increase the likelihood of
> ending the dictatorship and the war as soon as possible?

Nothing.

In  this situation, you don't oppose the regime in any public way until a better opportunity than the one you outline in the question presents itself. *See, e.g.,* North Korea, or Soviet era Albania.

Comment: re: "there isn't one".  Pinochet was a rare example where a dictator was removed mostly by not fulfilling the minimum legal requirements he set for himself.  But even that required some of the junta rejecting his request for a 2nd coup.  In the end, he was removed by law though.

Comment: @wrod The terms of the question appear to rule out this kind of scenario, noting that "all courts follow orders from above and bend laws as they wish"

Comment: alright.  just a thought.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe not for your very specific situation but as general advice living in similar situations, the only meaningful ways to oppose a regime:

- Try to leave the country. If everyone is doing it, problem solved.
- If you cannot leave: survive but don't support the country and the countries finances any more then necessary. Just work enough to survive. Try to avoid taking part in any suppression. Enjoy the time that is given to you privately.
- Children can bring a lot of meaning to life but they also might end up in a similar situation like you now. Take this into account when deciding to have offspring.
- Confide in your friends how unhappy you are with the regime but use ambiguous wording, so that you may save your neck. They may feel the same and need the support.
- Optional: If you feel adventurous, you have no kids, you're older and already lived a life and the time seems right: Try to form a resistance. It helps if your country has some remote mountain ranges or jungle though. And it's completely optional.

Summary: Run as fast as you can as far away as possible. There is nothing to win for you there. If you aren't doing yet so, start with preparations today. Emigrating to somewhere better is your personal best outcome, if you can do it.

Comment: *If you feel adventurous, you have no kids, you're old and the time seems right: Try to form a resistance* .....this is exactly one of the factors that make dictators sleep well every day: there aren't that many people satisfying all these characteristics....

Comment: +1. Could add all the taxes that you *won't* be paying in the dictator's country etc. They add up over time.

Comment: @Fizz Made the hint with the public finances more explicit. But really, nothing compares to fleeing if that is possible.

Comment: I'm totally open to edit proposals.